# make uncomitted updates in transaction visibile

Tags: mysql, innodb

Is it possible to make updates in an uncomitted transaction visible in another transaction?

Comment: maybe interesting? [READ UNCOMMITTED](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html#isolevel_read-uncommitted).However, It can get 'really interesting' if, say, a rollback happens on the transaction. etc.

Comment: @RyanVincent why don't you up your wording of your comment and add it as an answer?

Comment: What is the use case?  That is, Why do you want to see uncommitted values?